# How do you get a USB Drive's Name in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to get the name of my USB Drive.

Say I rename my USB Drive to "ZeroErrors".

and it is Drive letter "G:\" I want to use the drive letter to get the name of the USB Drive.

Answer (score 8):

Look at the [DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx) class.

```
string name = new DriveInfo("g").VolumeLabel;
```

or for all removable drives:

```
DriveInfo.GetDrives()
         .Where(x => x.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
         .Select(x => x.VolumeLabel)
```

Comment: seems a little wasteful and non-obvious to be doing all of that for a single string...

Comment: @RCIX - You're right, edited. I forgot about the simple constructor to get a specific drive.

Answer (score 4):

The following code should do the trick:

```
        DriveInfo drive = new DriveInfo("G:");
        Console.WriteLine(drive.VolumeLabel);
```

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yk7a1b0.aspx) on MSDN and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/logicaldiskinfo.aspx) on CodeProject should help you to get informations from your drives (included the USB).

But instead of use the letter of the drive, use the reference number.